# Process.GetProcesses returns processes of all logged on users?

Tags: c#-4.0, process

In a windows environment where multiple users are allowed to log on to a machine simultaneously, when we call `Process.GetProcesses()` , does it return the processes of the logged on user who is making this call or does it return processes of all the logged on users. I had a look at the MSDN page but couldnt find this information.

Comment: You see all the service processes.  They run with a different user account.  So yes.

Comment: You will find faster and easier solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7848879/2944961

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function returns all the process resources running on the local computer.
You can see it on MSDN (I also check it on my computer..)

> Return Value
>
> Type: `System.Diagnostics.Process[]`
>   An array of type Process that represents **all the process resources running on the local computer.**

If you are interesting in getting processes of specific user look at the following code - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14828/How-To-Get-Process-Owner-ID-and-Current-User-SID

Comment: Thanks. I was actually not sure whether 'all the process resources running on the local computer' translated into 'all the process resources running on the local computer for the logged on user' since we usually work on single log on machines . Did you check it on a multi user log on machine ?

Comment: In task manager, in order to show processes from all users, we require admin rights, so I am not sure if this would indeed return processes from all logged on users

Comment: I tried it and it is showing other users' processes eg NETWORK SERVICE, SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE. (My problem was GetProcessesByName wasn't matching for me but it turns out I have to omit ".exe")